# Integral of $\exp(i(u-v)^2)*\ln(u) d^2u$

Tags: integration

Calculate the integral of $$ \int\mathrm{d^2}u \ e^{i(\mathbf u- \mathbf v)^2} \ln(u)$$
where $ \mathbf u ,\mathbf v $ are two-dimensional vectors. Integration is carried out over the entire two-dimensional plane.

I tried to go into complex numbers, and take the contour of a semicircle, dividing the integral by the sum of $ \exp(i(\mathbf u+ \mathbf v)^2) $ and $ \exp(i(\mathbf u- \mathbf v)^2) $. But I can only find the differences of these terms

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)